# Firebase data structure: Attending school on date

Tags: json, firebase, nosql

I am currently looking into my first application using *Firebase* as the backend.

I have 2 models, *School* and *User*. Each user can sign up for a date to attend the school, so I also need a *Date*.

A *SQL* table would look like this:

`schools: id, name`

`users: id, name, email`

`schools_users: id, school_id, user_id, date`

What would be the proper way of designing this data structure in Firebase?

Comment: The Firebase documentation has a pretty decent guide on structuring data. And there are some quite relevant questions/answers on StackOverflow too. Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't specify any requirements, I suggest starting with the most naive mapping at first:

```
root
    schools
        1: "name of school1"
        2: "name of school2"
    users:
        1: { "name": "Maeh", "email": "2523229@stackoverflow.com" }
        2: { "name": "Frank", "email": "209103@stackoverflow.com" }
    schools_users:
        1_1: "20141031"
        1_2: "20130102"
```